# Padding of SHA-3

Tags: hash, sha-3

SHA-3 uses Padding, so the original message has a certain length.

In the case of SHA-3-512 each block has the size of 576, so any message must be padded, such that it is a multiple of the blocksize 576.

I know the rule that the padding is done via the formula

`p(m)=P10*1`

where P is a predetermined bit-String and the * is a placeholder, where an amount of 0 is inserted, such that the condition is met.

Now here comes the question: What happens, when we want to put a message of 575 bit into the algorithm? Obviously we are 1 bit short of the required length, and the padding rule is at least 3 bit long. What happens in that case?

Answer (score 4):

> What happens, when we want to put a message of 575 bit into the algorithm? Obviously we are 1 bit short of the required length, and the padding rule is at least 3 bit long. What happens in that case?

In that case, we just extends padding until it hits the next multiple-of-576 boundary; in this case, this means the padding is 577 bits long (and crosses the block boundary).

Answer (score 0):

From the [FIPS 202](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf) defines the padding. Multi-rate padding :

> The padding rule $pad10*1$, whose output is a $1$, followed by a (possibly
> empty) string of $0$s, followed by a $1$.

> **The padding rule**, pad, is a function that produces padding, i.e., a string with an appropriate length to append to another string. In general, given a positive integer $x$ and a non-negative integer $m$, the output $pad(x, m)$ is a string with the property that $m + len(pad(x, m))$ is a positive multiple of $x$. Within the sponge construction, $x = r$ and $m = len(N)$, so that the padded input string can be partitioned into a sequence of $r-bit$ strings.

Where $r$ is the block size or the rate. The $r$ can be calculated by $r = 1600 - 2\cdot r$

The below algorithm is the padding algorithm of SHA3 and internally determines the number of required zeros.

> **Algorithm 9: pad10*1(x, m)**
>
> - **Input**: positive integer $x$; non-negative integer $m$.
> - **Output**: string $P$ such that $m + len(P)$ is a positive multiple of $x$.
> - **Steps**:
>
>   1. Let $j = (– m – 2) \bmod x$.
>   2. Return $P = 1 \mathbin\| 0^j \mathbin\| 1$.

---

- A message with 575-bit size;

> What happens, when we want to put a message of 575 bit into the algorithm? Obviously we are 1 bit short of the required length, and the padding rule is at least 3 bit long. What happens in that case?

Call the algorithm **pad10*1(x, m)** with 575 ( pad10*1(576, 575) ), then $$j = (-575 -2) \bmod 576 =575$$ So the number of 0's is 575.

The padded message is $$m\mathbin\|1\,\underbrace{00\ldots00}_{575-zeroes}\,1$$

The total padding size is 577 which requires an extra block since the $r=576$.

Comment: Note: this is answer was written to extend poncho's answer in detail.